# Portfolio Optimization: Sharpe Ratio with two equally weighted assets

Tags: finance

I have an exercise:

`Suppose that µ1 = 5%, µ2 = 3%, σ1 = 35%, σ2 = 20%, κ = 40, w1 = 0.5, w2 = 0.5, rf = 1%. What is Sharpe Ratio of the given portfolio?`

Applying this function:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

But the correct answer given is: 0.128358764952167

Can you help me spot the mistake?

Comment: What is $K$ in this context?

Comment: Nevertheless the calculation is $$\frac{0.5\cdot 0.05+0.5\cdot 0.03-0.01}{\sqrt{0.5^2\cdot 0.35^2+0.5^2\cdot 0.2^2+2\cdot 0.35\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.1}}$$